# MongoDB Atlas Full-Text Search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

Does MongoDB Atlas Full-Text Search support following:

1. Autocomplete like in Elasticsearch (edge_ngram tokenizer):

Following query:

```
    GET /my_index/my_type/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "name": "brown fo"
            }
        }
    }
```

will return these documents:

```
    {
     "id": "12345",
     "name": "brown beautiful fox"
    }

    {
     "id": "123456",
     "name": "quick brown fox"
    }
```

2. Prefix queries like in Elasticsearch:

Following query:

```
    GET /_search
    {
        "query": {
            "match_phrase_prefix" : {
               "message" : "quick brown f"
            }
       }
    }
```

will return this document:

```
    {
     "id": "123456",
     "name": "quick brown fox"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's Atlas full text search, announced recently: https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/full-text-search